# Use multiple QnA services in one bot

Tags: node.js, botframework

I have multiple QnA services running, each with it's own `knowledgeBaseId` and `subscriptionKey`. I want to use them both in a single chatbot and I've written a piece of code which takes the user input and assigns the correct Knowledgebase details. However, I'm unable to get the 2nd QnA service to become active and the bot is linking only to the first service. What might be going wrong here?

**Sample code:**

```
var knowledgeId = "FIRST_QNA_SERVICE_KNOWLEDGE_ID"; 
var subscriptionId = "FIRST_QNA_SERVICE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID";

var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);

var qnarecognizer = new cognitiveservices.QnAMakerRecognizer({
    knowledgeBaseId: knowledgeId, 
    subscriptionKey: subscriptionId,
    qnaThreshold:0.3,
    top:1});

var intentrecognizer = new builder.IntentDialog();

var intents = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [intentrecognizer, qnarecognizer] });
bot.dialog('/', intents);

intents.matches('qna', [
    function (session, args, next) {
            args.entities.forEach(function(element) {
            session.send(element.entity);     
        }, this);           
    }
]);

intents.matchesAny([/hi/i, /main menu/i], [
    function (session) {
   builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Hi, What would you like to ask me about?", ["Service1","Service2"],{ listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button});

    },

       function (session, result) {
    var selection = result.response.entity;
           switch (selection) {
               case "Service1":
                    knowledgeId = "FIRST_QNA_SERVICE_KNOWLEDGE_ID"; 
                    subscriptionId = "FIRST_QNA_SERVICE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID";
                    session.send('You can now ask me anything about '+selection+'. Type \'main menu\' anytime to choose a different topic.')
                    session.endConversation();
                    return 

               case "Service2":
                    knowledgeId = "SECOND_QNA_SERVICE_KNOWLEDGE_ID"; 
                    subscriptionId = "SECOND_QNA_SERVICE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID";
                    session.send('You can now ask me anything about '+selection+'. Type \'main menu\' anytime to choose a different topic.')
                    session.endConversation();
                    return 

           }
   }

])
```

Answer (score 0):

You never updated the `knowledgeId`/`subscriptionId` on the QnAMakerRecognizer... that's the reason you are always seeing the first QnA service being called.

See if there is a way to update those values in the `QnAMakerRecognizer`.

Comment: Unable to get it to be updated. Can you suggest me a way?

Comment: Maybe just recreating the recognizer?

Answer (score 0):

Check out if my answer is valid to your purpose on this question:
[Multiple QnA Maker services for a single bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46430670/multiple-qna-maker-services-for-a-single-bot/46581116#46581116)

Hope you find it useful.