# Multiple QnA Maker services for a single bot

Tags: node.js, bots, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am developing a bot capable of answering different questions about different products. I was thinking on creating multiple services in QnA Maker for the different products, so the questions and answers don't get mixed. For example, questions related to "my profile" have different answers depending on the product, and I could use LUIS to handle that context.

Is that possible with multiple QnA services? Is there any other approach to this issue?

Comment: This is definitelly possible, but it's challenging to do properly. You can have separate intents for every QnA service, and then route queries.

Comment: I've asked almost same question few days back. Tried a few things too but couldn't get it working. Would be interested to know if you can get it to work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46409189/use-multiple-qna-services-in-one-bot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got it running with 2 different QnA services. The only solution I found was to make a call to the REST service instead of using the recognizer.

Here is the code to make a manual call to one service:

```
var fetch = require('node-fetch');
require('dotenv-extended').load({
    path: '../.env'
});

var get_restQnA = function (question, callback){

    qnaurl=`https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v2.0/knowledgebases/${process.env.KB_ID}/generateAnswer`;    
    fetch(qnaurl, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": process.env.QNA_KEY
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "question": question,
            "top": 1
        })
    }).then(response => {
        return response.json();
    }).then(data => {
        console.log('Here is the data: ', data);
    }).catch(err => {console.log(err);});
}

module.exports.get_restQnA = get_restQnA;
```

Since you are using the unique service ID, you just have to call each service in the different intents you have for LUIS.

Comment: There is now an [official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-dispatch?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs) for how to do this using the dispatch tool.